# Given a metric space $(M,d)$ and a cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{\mathbb{N}}$, show that $f(x) = \lim d(x,x_n)$ is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Here is my attempt:

Let $x,y\in M$. Then we have:

$|f(x)-f(y)| = |\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}d(x,x_n) - \lim\limits_{m\rightarrow\infty}d(y,x_m)| = |\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(d(x,x_n)-d(y,x_n)\right)| = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|d(x,x_n)-d(y,x_n)|\leq \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}d(x,y) = d(x,y)$

Can I combine the two limits this way so that I can use the reverse triangle inequality?

Comment: If you have shown that the two limits exist, yes. You are just using that addition is continuous on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ (aka the sum of two convergent sequences converges and the limit is the sum of the limits).

Comment: Yes I have shown the two limits must exist since the sequence $(x_n)_{\mathbb{N}}$ is cauchy. I was concerned because they have different indices and I couldn't remember if you can combine two such limits.

Comment: @TonyS.F. If you're concerned about indices being different, then reindex. $\lim_{m\to\infty} d(y,x_m) = \lim_{n\to\infty} d(y,x_n)$.

Comment: Yeah but just reindexing can get you into trouble sometimes, no? Like if you have a double sum, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty x_ny_m$ I cannot just reindex $m$ to $n$. I guess I am asking what are the conditions in which it's okay to reindex.

Comment: @TonyS.F. In your question you just need to use the fact that the sum of the limits of two sequences is equal to the limit of the sum of the sequences. This is an elementary property of limits.
What you're asking now is when $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} f(n,m) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n,m)$. The two are not really related, and the second one is of course much more subtle.